# How to obtain absolute path via relative path for 'other' project files?

Tags: python

How to obtain absolute path via relative path for 'other' project files, not those python file in the project, like Java?

```
D:\Workspaces\ABCPythonProject\

|- src
|   |-- com/abc
|       |-- conf.py
|       |-- abcd.py
|       |-- defg.py
|       |-- installation.rst
|- resources
|   |-- a.txt
|   |-- b.txt
|   |-- c.jpg
```

For example, I would like access 'a.txt' or 'b.txt' in python codes like 'abcd.py' in a simple manner with variable like 'resource/a.txt', just like a Java project in Java.

In short, I want to get '**D:\Workspaces\ABCPythonProject\resources\a.txt**' by '**resources\a.txt**', which is extremely easy to do in Java, but is seemingly extremely difficult to achieve in Python.

(If I use the built-in python methods like 'os.filePath.join(os.filePath.dirname(_file__), 'resources/a.txt')', os.path.dirname('resources/a.txt'), os.path.abspath('resources/a.txt'), ..., etc., the results is always "**D:\Workspaces\ABCPythonProject\com\abc\resources\a.txt**", a non-exit file path. )

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use those built-in python methods, but if you call your script in ../src/com/abc. Your `os.filePath()` function will execute in your current directory. Your current directory is your execution directory (directory of Python script!!)
At first you should change directory to access your .txt-file, because python does not execute in your "ABCPythonProject" directory.
Obviously you can not access to recourses/a.txt this way, because you have to change to directory "ABCPythonProject" to check this path.

```
os.chdir("D:\Workspaces\ABCPythonProject")
```

You can check your directory, you are currently in with:

```
print (os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 0):

This sample might benefit from a little cleaning, but it does the job.

```
import os
k = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(".", os.pardir)) # one level up
print k
k = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(k, os.pardir))   # two levels up
print k
k = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(k, 'resources/a.txt'))   # two levels down
print k
```

Starting in directory `C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Temp\src\com` output is

```
C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Temp\src
C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Temp
C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Temp\resources\a.txt
```